# Apache Tomcat testcase failure on s390x

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I have built Apache Tomcat 8.5.23 on Ubuntu 16.04 on s390x platform. While running the included tests, one of the tests is failing.

```
Test name: org.apache.coyote.http2.TestHttp2Limits
```

Expected: test should pass

Actual: test fails with following error:

```
Testcase: testHeaderLimits10x512k took 20.942 sec
        Caused an ERROR
End of input stream
java.io.IOException: End of input stream
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2TestBase$TestInput.fill(Http2TestBase.java:879)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2TestBase$TestInput.fill(Http2TestBase.java:858)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Parser.readFrame(Http2Parser.java:76)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Parser.readFrame(Http2Parser.java:69)
        at 
org.apache.coyote.http2.TestHttp2Limits.doTestHeaderLimits(TestHttp2Limits.java:258)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.TestHttp2Limits.doTestHeaderLimits(TestHttp2Limits.java:171)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.TestHttp2Limits.doTestHeaderLimits(TestHttp2Limits.java:165)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.TestHttp2Limits.doTestHeaderLimits(TestHttp2Limits.java:159)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.TestHttp2Limits.testHeaderLimits10x512k(TestHttp2Limits.java:153)
```

Same test passes on Ubuntu 16.04 on x86 platform. I am not able to find the root cause of this.